# laravel-mix purifyCss option not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, purifycss

im looking to use the purifyCss of laravel-mix. The fuction is working fine on a brand new installation but when i try to upgrade from an older version of laravel-mix nothing happens and no errors are shown.

this is the currect package.json file

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "purify-css": "^1.2.6",
    "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "velocity-animate": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

this is my `webpack.mix.js`

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({
    purifyCss: true
});

//default path
mix.setPublicPath('website');

//index
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/index/index-desktop.scss', 'css/index/index-desktop.min.css');
```

and this is a test blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="{{ session('user.language_code') }}">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caudex" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/index/index-desktop.min.css') }}">

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Also im using `yarn` and when i try `yarn run production` the css is never removed.

Comment: What version did you upgrade from and what version did you upgrade to?

Comment: from laravel-mix: ^1.0 to 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

For anyone having the same problem check your class/id and be sure they dont have any numbers on it.

Comment: Does this work for you with production mode? Isn't it stripping to much?

Answer (score 0):

There are more than accepted answer in this issue:

1. Indeed there is an issue with class names. With no changes in the purifycss they should match `/[a-z]+/`
2. The build may work for you with `run dev`, but fail while `run prod` because of the issue in the 3rd party repository (2nd level dependency) which strikes when you're purifying the minified css files, like bootstrap 4 for example. You can find detailed explanation in [PR](https://github.com/reworkcss/css/pull/118), and track the [issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1579).

For now you can use `npm install git://github.com/alex7r/css.git#master` (yes, I do prefer npm)